# Can I move to end of text inside tag with one move?

Tags: vim

Let's say I have some HTML:

```
<tag>Here is a bunch of text which is pretty long.</tag>
```

My cursor is on H.

I want to add some more text after the period. That is, I want to append text inside of the tag.

Right now, I'd probably `$` to the end of the line and then `b` until I get to the .

The end of the text inside the tag is not predictable, so I can't use `f.`.

What's the fastest way to get to the end of the text inside a tag?

Comment: Maybe defining a shortcut which searches for `</`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might not be the best way but one way to do this is to use `vit` to visually select the inner tag block. And then type `A` to append to the visually selected region.

So the command is

```
vitA
```

And if you just want your cursor at the end of the tag just use

```
vit<esc>
```

Comment: may I ask what is `vit`?

Comment: @SlakNation `v` starts visual mode `it` is select inner tag. `:help v` `:help it`

Answer (score 4):

I would do `t<a` instinctively.

But I like FDinoff's method better.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was going to post and exactly the same sentiment too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not one move but this gets the work done.
Assuming that you are in normal mode. Enter the following commands

```
vatA
```

What this does is, it visually selects the block including the tag and appends at the end of the line.