# Move the cursor to the start of text inside string

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

How to go (move the cursor) to the start of the contents of a string or any wrapper ([], {}. (). "". ..etc).

```
'some text here'
```

I want my cursor to be here:

```
'|some text here'
```

Comment: Heres a similar question except going to the end. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052167/can-i-move-to-end-of-text-inside-tag-with-one-move/19052298#19052298. After doing the visual section type `o` to move to the beginning, then escape.

Comment: @fdinoff so for this case it would be `vi"o` followed by escape.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Is there a way to make it enter insert mode directly?

Comment: try ... `vi"ovi` or if you many editing to do, shortcut it to a new  `\"` command `:map \" vi"ovi`

Answer (score 0):

% is the commmand to jump to matching ({[]}).  Depending on the version of matchit.vim, string delimiters are also supported.

:help 'matchpairs'